# Android Device orientation notification

Tags: android, rotation, orientation

I'm developing an android app. The application orientation is fixed to portrait mode.

One screen of the application contains a view, which i need to rotate according to device orientation. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Once try as follows

-> Specify orientation based on Activity.

-> Set orientation portrait for the activities you want.

-> Don't mention any orientation for the activity that you want to rotate based on the device orientation.

Comment: Actually, in that activity some parts i have to keep fixed to portrait mode.